# Form validation with regEx dosn't work in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm Working in login screen and i want t make the basic regEx for it.

I'm using custom UI Elements library from [BeautyTextField](https://github.com/hipoojan/BeautyTextfield)

this is my email and password input widgets

```
  Widget emailInput(){
    return BeautyTextfield(
                validator: (value)=>RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(email)?"Enter Valid Email":null,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:"Email"),
                cornerRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                width: double.maxFinite,
                height: 50,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.alternate_email),
                placeholder: "Email",
                onSaved: (value)=> email = value,
                fontFamily: "Muli",
            ); }

Widget passwordInput(){
    return BeautyTextfield( 
                    validator: (value)=> value.length == 6 ? "Enter Password of 6 Numbers":null,
                    cornerRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    height: 50,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    inputType: TextInputType.text,
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
                    obscureText: true,
                    placeholder: "Password",
                    onSaved: (value)=> password = value,

                );           
  }
```

and my form widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
return Form(
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /// Form Body

  key: signINformKey,
  child: 
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        emailInput(),
        passwordInput(),
        submitButton(),
        signUpButton(),
      ],
    ),

);}
```

I'm using this function on press on login button if the data is match with regEx so it will redirect to another page else it should show up a snack bar with message "Login Error", but it doesn't work and every time i click the login button it redirect to the other page even if the regEx is not matched because `signINformKey.currentState.validate()` is always return true

Comment: this i my repo in case you wanna check on something https://github.com/omarsherifs/iFound/tree/master/ifound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `onChange` to assign values inside input fields to variables and check on these variables

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `hasMatch()` function will return true if the string satisfies the regex. The code that you have in place for the `validator` always returns null because the email string doesn't match the regex that's why you get directed to next page instead of showing a Snackbar. You could add `!` this before the regex as this will inverse the result.

code:

```
validator: !RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(email)?"Enter Valid Email":null
```

Comment: it also signINformKey.currentState.validate()  return true only

Comment: Ok, I checked the code for the `BeautyTextfield` you modified it to accept `validator` but you forgot to change the `TextField` to `TextFormField` also to assign the `validator`.

Comment: it doesn't work also so i use on change to assign value of input filed to variables and check on these variable if it match or no .... thank you fayeed